# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS doesn't recognize CDROM/DVD device

Tags: 14.04, dvd, cd-drive

lshw doesn't find the CDROM:

```
juantxo@juantxo-OEM:~$ sudo lshw -class disk
*-disk                  
   descripción: ATA Disk
   producto: WDC WD1600BEVS-0
   fabricante: Western Digital
   id físico: 0.0.0
   información del bus: scsi@2:0.0.0
   nombre lógico: /dev/sda
   versión: 04.0
   serie: WD-WXH507045017
   tamaño: 149GiB (160GB)
   capacidades: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuración: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=0004d2c3
```

lsblk neither

```
juantxo@juantxo-OEM:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                 
├─sda1 ext4         /
├─sda2              
└─sda5 swap         [SWAP]
```

Nothing in dmesg:

```
    juantxo@juantxo-OEM:~$ less /var/log/dmesg|grep cdrom
    juantxo@juantxo-OEM:~$ less /var/log/dmesg|grep sr0
```

I have installed udftools

```
    juantxo@juantxo-OEM:~$ sudo apt-get install udftool
```

Also I have executed the libdbdcss2 script:

```
    juantxo@juantxo-OEM:~$ sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

After reading a lot of threads and questions about the same problem I have tried everything except changing the "slave" pin to "master" in the hardware of the cdrom device, but this is a laptop and I don't know if this can be done.

### Update

Starting the computer from the original Ubuntu 14.04 image from an USB drive the cdrom is properly detected:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -class disk
*-cdrom                 
   description: DVD writer
   product: DVD RW AD-5540A
   vendor: Optiarc
   physical id: 0.1.0
   bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
   logical name: /dev/cdrom
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   logical name: /media/ubuntu/SAMSUNG_CMFP
   version: 2.01
   serial: [
   capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
   configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=999,gid=999,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 state=mounted status=ready
```

### Update 2

The machine has 1.9GB RAM and I've been trying to install ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso. The md5sum for the actual installed version matches.
MD5  = 119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd

Now trying the 32 bit version ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso

### Update 3

The version `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso` is also failing.

MD5sum ok: `MD5 (ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso) = a8a14f1f92c1ef35dae4966a2ae1a264`

If I *burn* an USB with this version and choose the *"Try Ubuntu"* option then the *cdrom device*
**is recognised**.

If I install the same version through the option *"Install Ubuntu"* checking the options *"Update during install"* the final installation **is not recognising** the *cdrom device*.

If I install the same version through the option *"Install Ubuntu"* but this time NOT-checking the options *"Update during install"* and even keeping the computer out of network connections, the final installation **is not recognising** the *cdrom device*.

Comment: The drive should be detected and listed under *-cdrom when you issue the `sudo lshw -class disk` command. Are you sure the drive isn't damaged?

Comment: @ElderGeek My friend (the owner of the computer) says it works properly under WindowsXP. The device makes the proper noises when you put a CD into it. And the BIOS looks like it detects it. :/

Comment: It could be a bad connection. Have you tried the drive in a different system, different cables, Tried a different drive in the system?

Comment: I see that this drive is a slim laptop version PATA Which Sony has listed as End of Life. http://www.sony-optiarc.us/endoflifeproducts/dvddrives/slim/ad5540a.html There is no new firmware available for it http://www.sony-optiarc.us/support/downloads/dvdrwseries.html so scratch that idea.. Does the laptop it's in even meet the minimum system requirements for Ubuntu?

Comment: @ElderGeek the sad thing is that the basic 14.04 supports it (from the downloaded version) but some of the updates makes it to not be supported anymore. Is it really not hope? should I install WindowsXP :(

Comment: You could try booting the same kernel as exists on the installation media... If that works as advertised I'd report a bug... https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/KernelTeamBugPolicies

Comment: @ElderGeek the kernel is the same in both cases `3.13.0-32-generic`.. thanks a lot for your support, I've just given up on this, my friend is getting nervous and me too ;)

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "the basic 14.04 supports it"? If the kernel is the same, what might have changed that would cause a decrease in hardware support? I've seen increases in hardware support but not the reverse. Perhaps this is the result of adding something from an unsupported PPA?

Comment: @ElderGeek I get the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), I _"burn"_ an USB stick with it and start the machine choosing _"Try Ubuntu"_, with this set up the cdrom is detected. Then I choose _"Install Ubuntu"_, of course I choose to _"Update during the install"_ after this process the cdrom is not supported. The kernel test was a good idea, now looks like it is some other update which is causing the problem, but I can not have a Ubuntu that can't be updated because I'm gonna lost the cdrom support :/

Comment: Sounds like a rare bug. I've been unable to duplicate your results. Did you check the md5sum before "burning to USB"? The only other thing I can think of is to Install without updating during the install, making sure that the cdrom is still supported after a reboot, then installing updates one at a time and testing until we find the offending package.

Comment: are you installing the 32 or 64-bit version?

Comment: @ElderGeek *64* do you think is a good test if I try the *32* version? the machine has 1.9GB RAM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21412/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-fguillen).

Comment: Update from chat:  @fguillen states: I just gave up, I think this is an "only this computer" issue, has not point to be solved. The computer is not for me and the owner is pushing me to install WindowsXP .. I can not continue defending Ubuntu is easier.. because in this case it wasn't :)

Comment: Should we delete this question @fguillen ?

Comment: You might have similar problems under Windows: http://www.postseek.com/meta/dee33ebab1ad80e6ba438b14230396d0

Comment: @ElderGeek I wouldn't delete the question because even if it can be a _"only this computer"_ issue it is not an _"only me"_ issue. So maybe someone with the same computer (or cdrom device) can find some insight in this crazy epic story :). But if you insist I don't have any problem with delete it.

Comment: No, I don't insist. If anyone can benefit from this it's worth having IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Optiarc AD 5540A can be a bit flaky. You might want to replace it with a more recent drive as it doesn't appear that Optiarc is offering firmware updates for it ATM.

If your the adventurous sort and want to try out different firmware on the drive (which came out in 2006) there are a number of possibilities listed [here.](http://liggydee.cdfreaks.com/page/en/Optiarc-AD-5540A/)

Note: Changing the firmware on a device can have unpredictable results and I don't recommend doing it unless you are prepared to pitch it in the bin if something goes awry.

Sources:

http://www.sony-optiarc.us/endoflifeproducts/dvddrives/slim/ad5540a.html
http://www.postseek.com/meta/dee33ebab1ad80e6ba438b14230396d0